How to set replica identity full for a table having different owner?
I have two owners in my postgresql database e.g. testdb, I have some tables of owner1 and some tables of owner2. I am facing issue in setting replica identity full for tables of owner1 using owner2 login and vice versa.
Error message: Must be privileged user.
I added pgadmin role also to both of the user, still the issue is same

You could make owner2 a member of owner1:
GRANT owner1 TO owner2;

Then owner2 can ALTER TABLE for a table owned by owner1.
However, you cannot have both owner1 as a member of owner2 and vice versa. You will have to restructure and consolidate the ownership of your tables.
The alternative is to use a superuser. Superusers are not restricted by ownership and permissions.
